# What is the first piano song Kousei plays in the Your Lie in April live-action movie?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april, live-action-production

What is the first piano song Kousei plays in the *Your Lie in April* live-action movie? It was played during the first minute of the movie, from 0:00:20 up to 0:01:13.

Answer (score 1):

The song is called [Kimi no Sekai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9OvT-cEAaE). The tempo played during that scene is about 25% faster than the original.